# How do I write code to a button which must fire on both events onclick and onclientclick simultaneously with single click

Tags: c#, asp.net

iam writing code for button onclient event with js to print the webpage and onclick event for generating pdf and downloading it ..both must be done in a single action..
but when i cancel print which i onclient click event then oncick event is firing .

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     function PrintPage() 
     {
         window.print();
        return true;
     }
```

```
<asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server"  Text="PTPDF" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="Button3_Click1"  OnClientClick ="javascript:PrintPage();"    />
   </div>

protected void Button3_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {//here is the code for pdf generation,
```

this code must get fired automatically after onclient click event without users action}

Comment: add `UseSubmitBehavior = false` property and check if it works or not.

Comment: <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server"  Text="PTPDF" UseSubmitBehavior="false" OnClick="Button3_Click1" `UseSubmitBehavior="false"`  OnClientClick =`"return PrintPage();"`/>

Comment: i tried with that also its not working ,am not understanding why its not firing after writing UseSubmitBehavior = false ..

Answer (score 0):

Below `code` works perfectly on my end and `illustrates`on how both `OnClick` and `OnClientClick` works at a same time-

**ASPX -**

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Click.aspx.cs" Inherits="Click" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function confirmthis()
{
    document.getElementById('TextBox2').value = 'onclient works';    
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="return confirmthis();" Text="Click Me" /></div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Inline code -**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Click : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox1.Text = "OnClick works";
    }
}
```

Please `paste` the above `code` at your end and let me know if it still doesn't work.

Thanks!!

Comment: its working when i keep print after that if condition ..i understood the problem is till now it didnot return true or false but can we do this without confirmation like if condition is displaying some message and if click ok then its redirecting to onclick event .can we do this without showing some message which we have written in if condition

Comment: Please check updated code above, without `If condition()`, `without confirmation box` and `without return statement`. Hope this helps!!

Comment: this is correct but for print statement this code is not working without if condition.i want trigger to pdf downloading only after print is done ..can we do it in any other way..

Comment: i have a doubt ,when am trying to like this its not firing on onclick event function printDiv(divName) {
     var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
       
     window.print();

        document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
     if (confirm("Do you want to save this copy as pdf?"))
            
     {
         return true;
     }